# t in question titles and other larger fonts is too short

Tags: bug, design

The lower case t in question titles and other places where the font is larger than body seems to be poorly formed. It's a bit too short, typically the same height as the top of the curve of the lower case e rather than being a touch above it.

Here is what it looks like to caseyr547:

[image: caseyr547]

Apparently this isn't universal as Caleb (Linux/Xorg/Chrome) doesn't have the same issue. At risk of being recursive here is how his browser renders, which the other screen shot showing for reference:

[image: caleb]

Comment: Can you provide an image? It looks fine to me. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: @AndrewLeach it's both chrome and firefox 21.0. I'm not the only one who noticed either. If you find a t and e next to each other it's particularly stark. Such as in the title of http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1785/can-something-be-done-to-these-illegible-info-in-the-graduated-version-of-the-si

Comment: I notice it too in chrome it looks like half the texas tech symbol. http://www.ttu.edu/ its only off a few pixels though.

Comment: Funny, this definitely isn't a problem on my computers/browsers. I see quite clearly in the screenshot from casey what you're talking about, but the same thing renders fine on my screen. I winder if this is a bug in the font itself and the Windows font  subsystem is screwing you up. Single letter rendering issues aren't likely to be a CSS site theme thing!

Comment: For reference my observations are from Windows 7 *and* 8 with latest stable Chrome on Win 8 and Firefox 21.0 on Win 7.